# Resolve local subdomain on apache for paths within user dir

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, mod-rewrite, subdomain, localhost

On Apache 2.2.x I've activated [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html). I used the default setup, so that `http://localhost/~name/` will be connect with `~name/public_html/` and a path within public_html, e.g. `~name/public_html/mySite` can be reached through `http://localhost/~name/mySite`.

How can I achieve, that the same path can be reached through `http://mySite.name.localhost/`? I don't want a manual approach like it is suggested in other SF questions (such as [Apache: Setting up local test server with subdomains](https://serverfault.com/q/133921/53624)), but rather want an automatic mapping of all available paths to the corresponding URL.

I think, several steps will need to be taken: Change mod_userdir configuration, so that the subdomain of localhost will be connected with all available user names on the machine. The second step would maybe include the usage of mod_rewrite, so that the subsubdomain could be matched to the path within ~name/public_html...

What would be your prefered way?

EDIT:

The solution is flagged. I some small modifications to meet special requirements and added comments:

```
RewriteEngine on
# check, if not redirected yet
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# look for URLS like 'subdir.username.localhost'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.([^.]+)\.localhost$
# check if /home/username/public_html/subdir is a directory or symbolic link
RewriteCond /home/%2/public_html/%1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond /home/%2/public_html/%1 -l
# rewrite to default target
RewriteRule ^(.+) %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
# rewrite to /home/username/public_html/subdir
RewriteRule (.+)\.([^.]+)\.localhost(?::\d+)?(.*) /home/$2/public_html/$1$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar need a few weeks ago.  I solved it using mod_rewrite, by putting this in my default vhost definition:

```
RewriteEngine on
 # look for URLS like 'subdir.username.localhost'
 RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.localhost$
 RewriteCond /home/%2/public_html/%1 -d
 RewriteRule ^(.+) %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
 RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.localhost(?::\d+)?(.*) /home/$2/public_html/$1$3 [L]
```

There is some more info at https://gist.github.com/744971, including getting username.localhost to resolve to /home/username/public_html

Comment: Since some of my 'subdirs' contain dots, I rewrote parts of the regex. Also some paths are symbolic links, so I added another RewriteCondition. Since your solution does exactly what I asked for, I flaged it as the solution but will add my changes to the initial question.
Great work!